# Deduce Sheffer's classification of orthogonal polynomials of A-type 0

Tags: lie-groups, orthogonal-polynomials, classification, hermite-polynomials, laguerre

Theorem 1.9 in Daniel Galiffa and Tanya Riston's paper, [An elementary approach to characterizing Sheffer A-type 0 orthogonal polynomial sequences](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/involve-a-journal-of-mathematics/volume-8/issue-1/An-elementary-approach-to-characterizing-Sheffer-A-type-0-orthogonal/10.2140/involve.2015.8.39.full), 2015, presents without proof Isador Sheffer's classification of orthogonal polynomials of A-type 0 into what are now known as Laguerre, Hermite, Charlier, Meixner, Meixner-Pollaczek and Krawtchouk polynomials.

Please explain how to arrive at this classification. I understand that these are the orthogonal polynomials $P_n(x)$ with $P_{-1}(x)=0$ and $P_0(x)=1$ which are A-type 0, which is to say, they take on the form

$A(t)e^{xH(t)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P_n(x)t^n$

where $A(t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nt^n$, $a_0=1$, $H(t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}h_nt^n$, $h_1=1$. I suppose that all of the coefficients are rational or perhaps complex rational.  I understand from their paper that the parameters in the recurrence relation are all determined by the values $a_1$, $a_2$, $h_2$, $h_3$.  As an aside, I am curious how these polynomials relate to elements of Lie groups and Lie algebras.

I am not able to access the original paper Sheffer, [Some properties of polynomial sets of type zero](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-5/issue-3/Some-properties-of-polynomial-sets-of-type-zero/10.1215/S0012-7094-39-00549-1.short), 1939.  Apparently, it's related to Meixner's earlier work.

I have purchased Theodore Chihara's book, An Introduction to Orthogonal Polynomials, 1978.  He writes the recurrence relation

$P_{n+1}(x) = (x - (dn + f)) P_n(x)  - n(gn + h) P_{n-1}(x)$

In Section V.4, Chihara presents but does not derive a fivefold classification, which I order and name thus:

- $g=0$, $d=0$ Hermite
- $g=0$, $d\neq 0$ Charlier
- $d\neq 0$, $d^2-4g=0$ Laguerre
- $d^2-4g>0$ Meixner
- $d^2-4g<0$ Meixner-Pollaczek

The term $d^2-4g$ reminds me of the discrimant in the quadratic equation and thus the classification of the conics.  I am curious how to arrive at the different cases.

Readings that might have what I am looking for include:

[W. A. Al-Salam. Characterization Theorems for Orthogonal Polynomials](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-009-0501-6_1)

Mourad E. H. Ismail. Classical and Quantum Orthogonal Polynomials in One Variable.

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: W.A.Al-Salam's article is the lead article in the book Orthogonal Polynomials: Theory and Practice, edited by Paul Nevai.  The pages that I need, 1-4, are included in the Kindle preview. https://www.amazon.com/Orthogonal-Polynomials-Theory-Practice-Science/dp/9401067112  I will try to make sense of it and answer my question but I'm glad if somebody else might write this out.